# "cmake -g "XCode" " Creates a library, not executable

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

When I set up an XCode project with CMake using `cmake -G "Xcode"`, and open it in Xcode, the option to run is greyed out, and I can only build the project. Looking around revealed that this is probably because XCode sees it as a library and not an executable. How do I use cmake so that I can run the file after building it?

EDIT: Here's my CMakeLists.txt

```
# Get the exercise name from the current directory
get_filename_component(exercise ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
# Basic CMake project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
# Name the project after the exercise
project(${exercise} CXX)

# Locate Boost libraries: unit_test_framework, date_time and regex
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.55 REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework date_time regex)

# gcc/clang won't enable C++11 features without this flag
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "(GNU|Clang)")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
endif()

# Configure to run all the tests?
if(${EXERCISM_RUN_ALL_TESTS})
    add_definitions(-DEXERCISM_RUN_ALL_TESTS)
endif()

# Make an executable that runs the exercism unit tests against the implementation
function(exercism)
    # Replace -'s with _'s to get a filename from the exercise name
    string(REPLACE "-" "_" file ${exercise})
    # Implementation could be only a header
    if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${file}.cpp)
        set(exercise_cpp ${file}.cpp)
    else()
        set(exercise_cpp "")
    endif()
    # Build executable from sources and headers
    add_executable(${exercise} ${file}_test.cpp ${exercise_cpp} ${file}.h)
    # We need boost includes
    target_include_directories(${exercise} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    # We need boost libraries
    target_link_libraries(${exercise} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    # Run the tests on every build
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${exercise} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${exercise})
endfunction()

exercism()
```

This was included with a set of exercises that ask you to write files that pass the tests thrown at it using Boost. I'm not familiar with cmake but I need the Xcode project that it creates to be runnable.

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt is what sets all this up.  Show us the relevant portions.

Comment: There should be two targets in your Xcode project: the library project containing your implementation and the unit test project that executes the tests.  You can't "run" the library project, only the unit test project.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a similar project, and I find that my "Products" in XCode are all red and the "Run" command is greyed out.

If you look at the "Identity and Type" pane for your test executable product, you'll probably find that the path listed is not the actual output path.

I have made this match and the run command be enabled by tinkering with the build settings.  The "Build Products Path" for the top-level project seems to determine what path is expected in the "Products" list.  The "Build Products Path" for each individual target seems to determine where the product output actually goes.  So by manually changing these until the expected and actual output match, you can enable your "Run" command.

There's probably an adjustment to the CMake file that will automate this, but I haven't figured out what it is yet.